# Symfony 2: Doctrine constraints in forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have an Entity with the field `url`, this entity is being persisted to the database uppon sending a form based on the same entity.

I can set constraints to the form type in `validation.yml` along with custom messages like `NotBlank` and `Url`. That's all fine. But when I try to persist an entity that already exists in the DB I get an error saying that the value already exists (`url`).

How can I set a custom message for this `UniqueEntity` constraint?

I tried adding `UniqueEntity` in the validation.yml, but it is in a different namespace and I cannot understand how it works, or how to setup it. It is there by default, couse `url` is defined as unique field in the original entity annotation, but how to change the error message??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution to my own problem.

All validations can be defined in validation.yml, but since I am using annotations to define my entities, it is better to put all validations, messages etc. inside those annotations.

It was enought to set `@Assert\NotBlank` for a not blank field and `@ORM\UniqueEntity(message="my custom error")` for the being unique validation.

I'm sorry for flooding the site with my question, but I hope someone might find this useful..

P.S.: Annotations or YML makes no difference, the setup is the same. I suppose in my case it should have been something like:

```
Namespace\Class:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: url
            message: "My custom message"
```

It is quite flexible, thought I don't see how we could set different messages if different fields are already present in the db...